# How to allow the user to create/produce new webpages into your website using Jquery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a database in which there are **teams** and every team is working on different **projects**. Each project then further have **tasks**.

So, basically, there are three tables.

1. Team
2. Project
3. Task

Now, my user interface contains two things,

1. A webpage for **each project** that displays all the tasks of that Project and allows user to add new tasks into that project.
2. A webpage for **each team** that displays all the members of that team (member is also another table) and allows user to add new members into that particular team.

I made one sample project and one sample team. I added few sample tasks for that project and also few members for that team and then created sample pages for both project and team.

The page for project displays all the tasks of that Project... Similarly, if I create another project and make page for that, it would correctly display tasks of that 2nd project. The functionality of Adding New Tasks is also working correctly.

The page for Team displays all the members of that team. Similarly, if I create another team, my webpage would show members of that particular team.

My problem is, I want to **allow the user to add new projects and new teams.**
And then allow him to add new tasks into that newly added project and also new members into those newly added teams. This is easy because all the thing is being done on **single page**

But how do I make **new web-pages** for those newly added projects and newly added teams? I can't seem to understand this at all.
Suppose the web-page for my first project is,

```
website/project1.php
```

^This web-page will display all the tasks which are being done under the project of ID = 1. Plus, it allows the user to add new tasks into this project. This much, I have done. But **I want to make similar pages for new projects, that have all these functionalities**

Now, If a user adds a 2nd project, I want a new web-page to be created as,

```
website/project2.php
```

I can't seem to understand how can I do this.

Plus, not only should a new web-page be created but also it should display all the tasks that have project_ID = 2. Moreover, this web-page should also allow the user to add new tasks for the same project (basically, I want to know some way to retrieve the ID of the project from the URL)

And the same should be done for the Teams.

I tried searching this problem up and I am sure it is somewhere answered as well but I couldn't find the right words to look it up. I have been searching for two days and have watched several videos as well but nothing really helped that much.

Please note that I am using XAMPP Local Host for development. I am working with **Bootstrap, Jquery/Javascript, AJAX, PHP etc.**

Comment: You'll need to create templates that render the correct information based on the, for example, URL. Let's say you have `website/projects/1`, then the `projects` template should be used and project 1 should be rendered on the `projects` template. This way you can create an infinite amount of projects that all use the same layout, but only the data differs based on the `id` of each project. This is how most websites operate. You'll need to work this all out on your own, since you're basically asking for a tutorial.

Comment: Don't create different files for each project. Create one singe file template called "project.php" and then pass the project id to it, like in a query string: `project.php?id=1` (or use some router to make nice URL's). Then you just get that id, fetch what you need from your database and dynamically fill out the page/template with the correct data. I would recommend using one of the many MVC frameworks out there, like Laravel or similar since they all come with good structures, routers, templating engines etc.

Comment: yes, I understand what you are saying. I have created that project.php website. That project.php will work according to the ID given to it. I can also easily retrieve the ID of the newly created project (or the project user clicks on, say the project with id = 1) but again the issue is, how do I open that project.php?id=1 file and then after opening, how do I retrieve id from the URL? I really can't seem to find anything on this... I am working on MVC model using PHP but haven't used Laravel and unfortunately do not have enough time to learn Laravel for this purpose right now :/

Comment: `how do I open that project.php?id=1`...in your browser like any other URL. You can create links to it within your other pages. `how do I retrieve id from the URL`...using `$_GET`, in core PHP, any relevant PHP tutorial would show you. If you're using some special pre-built MVC framework it may have some abstraction over that, but in MVC the URL parameters are always made available inside the action methods in some way, the specifics will depend on the framework you're using but you will definitely be able to access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one is you want to ask https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```
<?php 
//header

//main
//From url get id value
$id = $_GET["id"]
include("file/$id")

//footer
?>
```